# Clash of clans hog rider

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am fresh town hall 8. My hogs are upgrading in laboratory but for now I only have level 1 hogs and I am in war where my mirror is also town hall 8 but he is a maxed one. The whole base is completely spread all over the field I am wondering if I could defeat the base with my hogs and level 3 heal spells. Some people say that hogs can do it but I don't want to take any risk. Are level  1 hogs really strong enough to make that happen against a maxed town hall 8?

Comment: When I was at TH8, the best, alebit expensive, strategy was to use air. Load up your army with all drags, take 2 lightning spells and a rage and quake. Then request a poison and another drag in clan castle to take out the opponents CC troops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my part I would say hogs are not that strong but it is the heal spell which can change everything.

I would suggest you to take all heal with 28 hogs and leave the rest wizards and take level 4+ hogs and haste in clan castle.
If you have enough Dark Elixir just fill with hogs and valkyries and then clear three points of main defenses (archer tower/cannon), and let the valkyries handle the fourth one. It is all about proper placement.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer the question without looking at the actual base and being experience enough to scout where the bombs would be.

Being a scattered max TH8 I would say that there are plenty of places where a dual Giant Bomb can be and your hogs will RIP. **So, to your hypothetical question I would say NO**. They are not strong enough for a scattered max TH 8, except if you are experienced enough to know where the GB can be and calculate it well.